# AppIcon and name not getting reflected in Apps using Apple signin page under iPhone settings - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-sign-in, xcode11.4

I'm using apple sign-in feature in my app. When check the details of my app in "apps using your Apple Id" page in iPhone settings my app name and Icon is not getting updated there. Please refer the below image.

I'm using Xcode 11.4.1 and add all the required resolutions for app icon

[image]

Can someone help me on how to update the app-icon and app name under "apps using your Apple Id" page under settings

Comment: Apparently this issue will be resolved once the app is published in Appstore.

Comment: No needed to published the app, Once app uploaded on appStore and add in build , not to review just add there. once you will able to see app icon of your on appStore developer section than also able to see icon in device for sign in.